# advice on jQuery / Css IE 7-8-9 issues

Tags: jquery, html, css, image, internet-explorer

im trying to create a portfolio based website with a stack of floating dynamic staling images, so far i've made it work via jQuery and css for chrome and Firefox (newest release anno. 2012)

my issue is (as always) IE 7-8-9, i can't wrap my head around what may break it on this platform, my best guess is it's a jQuery cross issue ?

[check this jsFiddel](http://jsfiddle.net/9Xv8L/1/)

[or check my online exampel here](http://test.madeofdots.com/jq/02/)

What im looking for is some advice on where i may go wrong since i now have gray hair trying to figure it out on my own, any advice, ideas, articles etc. are more than welcome

thanks in advance
Mads

jQuery code:

```
$(window).load(function () {
    plottingData();
    resizeImage();
});

$(window).resize(function () {
    plottingData();
    resizeImage();
});

function plottingData() {
    var image = $('.box img');
    var divW = $(".box").width();
    var divH = $(".box").height();
    var imgW = image.width();
    var imgH = image.height();
    $('.outputText').html('DIV CONTAINER W: ' + divW + ' H: ' + divH + '  ::  imgW: ' + imgW + ' : imgH: ' + imgH);
}


function resizeImage() {
    $("img").each(function () {
        var maxWidth = $(".box").width();; // Max width for the image
        var maxHeight = $(".box").height();; // Max height for the image
        var maxratio = maxHeight / maxWidth;
        var width = $(this).width(); // Current image width
        var height = $(this).height(); // Current image height
        var curentratio = height / width;
        // Check if the current width is larger than the max

        if (curentratio > maxratio) {
            ratio = maxWidth / width; // get ratio for scaling image
            /*
            $(this).css("width", maxWidth); // Set new width
            $(this).css("height", height *ratio); // Scale height based on ratio
            */
            $(this).css("width", "100%");
            $(this).css("height", "auto");
        } else {
            /*
            ratio = maxHeight / height; // get ratio for scaling image
            $(this).css("height", maxHeight);   // Set new height
            $(this).css("width", width * ratio);    // Scale width based on ratio
            */
            $(this).css("width", "auto");
            $(this).css("height", "100%");
        }

    });
}
```

Comment: You have extra semi-colons `var maxWidth = $(".box").width();;` and `var maxHeight = $(".box").height();;`

Comment: @user125697: That doesn’t matter, it just results in an “empty statement” that does nothing.

Comment: @CBroe I know, I just wanted it to be cleaned up :P

Answer (score 0):

Try that:

```
...
var box = $(this).parent(".box");
var maxWidth = box.width();
var maxHeight = box.height();
...
```

same width `plottingData` you'll have to iterate there, too.
Can you tell me which height of all the boxes and images you're getting?
You're just lucky that their all the same size it seems. Apply the rules for each box and image.

Comment: Naturally jQuery was not the problem but the support for CSS in IE 7 and 8, 9 behaves kind of ok, @media is not supporter along with opacity and border-box..... among MANY many other things. i've decided, since it's my own portfolio, that i will not support IE6-7-8 only from IE9+ and the latest chrome, firefox and safari ;).. it's time to say enough is enough from IE... yes it suxx.